# Ayuda con funciones de python

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Hice un código que utiliza unas funciones. Tales funciones le dan un valor a n y a medida que se llaman pues el valor de n cambia (estas funciones están al principio del código). Lo que pasa es que al ejecutar el script, así no llame las funciones ellas se ejecutan todas y le dan un valor final a n como si las hubiera llamado todas y nunca las llamé ¿Qué sucede?

**mi Aplicacion Principal**

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.nfont = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=15, slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")
        def p1():

            global n
            n = 1
            print ("Probando")
```

**Mi Pagina 1**

```
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(bg="black")
        # Declaramos y llamamos la tabla
        x = 1

        tabla = PhotoImage( file="tabla00.PNG")
        labeltabla = Label(self, image=tabla)
        labeltabla.image = tabla
        labeltabla.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white", text="¿Tu número se encuentra en esa tabla?", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        si = tk.Button(self, text="Sí", command=SampleApp.p1(), width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
        no = tk.Button(self, text="No", width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
        pasar = tk.Button(self, text="Pasar a la siguiente página", width=20, height=3, relief="raised", borderwidth=5, command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page2"))
        si.pack()
        no.pack()
        pasar.pack()
```

**Mi inicio de la Aplicacion**

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # Definimos funciones básicas de la ventana
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(bg="black")
        # Creamos y damos caracteristicas a los frames
        titulo = tk.Label(self, bg="black", text="Bienvenidos...", fg= "white", font=controller.title_font)
        instrucciones = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white", text="Instrucciones:", font=controller.title_font)
        label = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white" , text="\nEste es un pequeño juego matemático que consiste en que tú piensas un número \nentre el 1 al 1023, y yo adivino cuál es.", font=controller.nfont)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white", text="\nVas a pensar en un número antes de empezar. Al momento de que le des al botón, \nsaldrá una imagen con muuuchos números. No te asustes, los números están en orden. \nEs decir que si piensas en el 108, este debe estar entre el 107 y el 109 o lo que más se acerca.", font=controller.nfont)
        # Empaquetamos los labels
        titulo.grid(row=0)
        label.grid(row=1)
        instrucciones.grid(row=2, pady=20)
        label2.grid(row=3, padx=30)
        # Boton
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Empezar",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page1"), width=20, height=5, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
        button1.grid(row=4, pady=50)
```

Comment: Es casi imposible adivinar qué está pasando sin ver el código. Puedes meter algún `print("Probando")` dentro de alguna de esas funciones para verificar si se llaman en realidad o no. Si no, otra parte de tu código está cambiando el valor de `n `. Sería mejor si pusieras un mínimo ejemplo que muestre el problema.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu comentario. Puse el "Probando" en la primera función y me aparece apenas abro la ventana. Me parece muy extraño porque  se supone que las funciones no se ejecutan sino hasta que son llamadas. Pero el probando salió y yo no lo había llamado. No pongo código porque es muy largo y seguro te aburre :( Aunque voy a poner la clase que contiene las funciones a ver si ves algo raro.

Comment: Por eso te decia lo de "un ejemplo minimo". No pedía tu código original completo si no otro, lo más corto posible, que siga mostrando el mismo problema.

Comment: Ya, ahí puse las funciones. Pero el problema es que a penas lo ejecuto me muestra el print y nunca llamé la función p1

Comment: puedes postear todo el codigo?... y estas asiendo mal uso de global si es una clase usa self.n, si son solo funciones declar la variable antes de las funciones!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eRVux23U ahí está el código completo. Es una app multiframe. Cada clase es un frame, es intuitivo. Y las clases del Page1 a Page 10 tienen un label que se llama _si_ y ahí se invocan las funciones. Gracias por la ayuda :D y por lo de la identación si es tema de copiar y pegar porque la app si sirve, lo único que no sirve es eso que lec omento.

Comment: Moraleja: Hay que mostrar el código relevante para obtener una respuesta útil. Espero que la respuesta de @abulafia resuelva tu problema! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A la vista del código que pone el usuario como parte de la pregunta, que contiene cosas de este estilo:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def p1():    
        global n
        n = 1
        print ("Probando")
```

Es evidente que si al lanzar el programa le aparece la cadena `"Probando"`, es que la función `p1()` ha sido ejecutada en algún momento aunque diga que no.

Ya que finalmente el usuario en un comentario proporciona el código completo en un enlace a [este pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eRVux23U) (y del cual posteriormente [@JackNavaRow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow), muy amablemente ha añadido a la pregunta los fragmentos relevantes), he sido capaz de detectar el punto en que se llaman a esas funciones.

Por ejemplo, como parte del código (que no reproduzco completo pues es muy largo), aparece este constructor en otra clase:

```
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(bg="black")
        # Declaramos y llamamos la tabla
        x = 1

        tabla = PhotoImage( file="tabla00.PNG")
        labeltabla = Label(self, image=tabla)
        labeltabla.image = tabla
        labeltabla.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self, bg="black", fg= "white", text="¿Tu número se encuentra en esa tabla?", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack()

        si = tk.Button(self, text="Sí", command=SampleApp.p1(), width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
        no = tk.Button(self, text="No", width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
        pasar = tk.Button(self, text="Pasar a la siguiente página", width=20, height=3, relief="raised", borderwidth=5, command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page2"))
        si.pack()
        no.pack()
        pasar.pack()
```

Y ahí podemos ver la llamada, en la línea que crea el botón `si`:

```
    si = tk.Button(self, text="Sí", command=SampleApp.p1(), width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
```

Tu fallo es que en lugar de proporcionar la referencia a la función a ejecutar, que sería `SampleApp.p1`, has llamado a esa función y proporcionas el valor devuelto. Tendría que haber sido así:

```
    si = tk.Button(self, text="Sí", command=SampleApp.p1, width=10, height=2, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
```

Y como este, tienes otras muchas creaciones de botones que también invocan su función `command` en lugar de pasar una referencia a las mismas.

**Aclaración**. Por completar el análisis del problema, la clase que representa al punto de entrada de la aplicación, en su constructor, itera por el resto de clases y va creando los frames instanciando todas esas clases.

Cada una de esas clases, al ser instanciada, ejecuta su constructor, y dentro de todos esos constructores se crea un botón `si` al que se intenta asignar como `command` cada una de las funciones `SampleApp.p1`, `SampleApp.p2`, `SampleApp.p3`, etc...  Pero en todos los casos se está cometiendo el mismo error antes mencionado, por lo que esas funciones en vez de ser meramente referenciadas, son ejecutadas.

Por tanto, al cargar la clase principal, se acaban ejecutando todas esas funciones a través de los constructores del resto de las clases que se van instanciando.